# When I pass multiple values in Provider server did not show anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapping, react-context

When I send single value but doesn't works when I pass multiple value as an array.

### NotesState

```
import NoteContext from './notesContext'
import  {useContext,useState} from 'react'

const NotesState = (props)=>{
    const notesInitial = [
            {
              "_id": "636bcdfg76b1667854ff40c93612b",
              "title": "new Title",
              "description": "this my Updates title",
              "tag": "General",
              "date": "2022-11-09T15:29:47.306Z",
              "__v": 0
            },
            {
              "_id": "636btyc76b168fg54ff40c93612b",
              "title": "new My title",
              "description": "this my Updates title 2",
              "tag": "General",
              "date": "2022-11-09T15:29:47.306Z",
              "__v": 0
            },
            {
              "_id": "636bc76b16854fff40c93612b",
              "title": "new new title",
              "description": "this my Updates title 3",
              "tag": "General",
              "date": "2022-11-09T15:29:47.306Z",
              "__v": 0
            },
          ]
          const [note, setNote] = useState(notesInitial)
      
          // Add A Note
          const addNote = ()=>{

          }
          // Delete Note
          const deleteNote = ()=>{

          }
          // Edit Note
          const editNote = ()=>{

          }
    
    return (
        <NoteContext.Provider **value = {{note, setNote, addNote , deleteNote,editNote}}**>
         {props.children}
         </NoteContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default NotesState;
```

When I pass single value (note) it works fine - **value = {note}**. But when I pass multiple value it doesn't show anything.

### Notes component

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react'
import noteContext from "../context/notes/notesContext"
import Noteitem from './Notesitem';


const Notes = () => {
    const context = useContext(noteContext);
    const {notes}= context;
    //  
    return (
      <div className='row my-3'>
      <h2>Your Notes</h2>
        {notes.map((note)=>{
          return <Noteitem note = {note}/>
        })}
      </div>
    )
}

export default Notes
```

values = {{note , setNote, addNote}}

Answer (score 0):

did you try it like this  i think it should work because you are not taking all the values from context and you are calling note with a different name (notes with s)

```
const Notes = () => {
    const context = useContext(noteContext);
    const {note, setNote, addNote , deleteNote,editNote}= context;
    //  
    return (
      <div className='row my-3'>
      <h2>Your Notes</h2>
{note.map((item)=>{
  return <Noteitem note = {item}/>
})}
      </div>
    )
}
```